# Sending piece of model data back to controller as variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view which imports data from a model and I need to make action links that send back a piece of the model data back to the controller

## Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.User>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Request", "Index", new { userNumber = //model.Number value })
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried:

`new { userNumber = model.Number })`  //The name model does not exist in the current context

`new { userNumber = Model.Number })` //IEnumerable does not contain a definition for ModelNumber (even though it does)

Comment: For the first line: In the context of a cshtml page.  Model is a property that is capitalized.

For the second line:  Check that the top of your page contains the @model directive, and if it doesn't.  Include it with the type of your model.  Example: `@model The.Name.Of.Your.Model.Class`

Comment: I have updated my code to show what I have up top

Comment: Your model is a collection... There is no `IEnumerable<T>.Number` member. Are you trying to create rows for each user in your collection?

Comment: Well yes I need to display the information is a table so I figured this was best but I need to make the table headings sortable so thats why I'm trying to make the action links but the action links need to send back information on who the user is which is stored in the `.Number`

Comment: Edit the value of userNumber as @model.Number.

Comment: Gives me the same error as above, If I remove IEnumerable it works fine but then I cant use a foreach loop on it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a collection of users as your model, you need to iterate over your model with a foreach loop to get the values present on `App.Models.User`.  The Number property would presumably be on your `App.Models.User` class, not on `IEnumerable<App.Models.User>`.

Something like this would work:

```
@foreach(App.Models.User user in Model) {

    Html.ActionLink("Request", "Index", new { userNumber = user.Number })

}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me because I have multiple headers and it will spit out like 5 of each header.

I figured out it works fine as long as its not IEnumerable. Is there a way I can just use `@model App.Models.User` at the top and then when I need to loop the data out with a @foreach I can just call IEnumerable at that point?

Comment: No. If you need to interact with an enumerable, then your model needs to be an enumerable. The problem here isn't the definition of your model but a logical question. You have a list of users and you want to create a link composed from a user's `Number`. Which user's number should that be? Either, you loop through the list and generate a link for each user, or *you* need to somehow pick a user from the list. MVC rightly can't and won't make this decision for you.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy You can use `@model App.Models.User` as long as your controller code is sending down a single user.  Based upon the model in the code you provided in the question, it appears that you want to interact with a list of users.  If this is not the case then you can switch the `@model` directive to `App.Models.User` and you can then calls to `@Model.Number` should work.  If your controller is sending down a collection of users, then you will need to either iterate over them in the view or pick out a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Under your `Views\Shared` folder, add a `DisplayTemplates` folder.

Inside that folder, create a view called `User.cshtml`.

Add this:

```
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Request", "Index", new { userNumber = model.Number })
        </th>
    </tr>
```

Then in your view, add this:

```
<table>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model)
</table>
```

Comment: While this will technically work, this assumes that every time you want to display a user, you want it to display like this. The OP made no such assertion, and I doubt that was the intent.

Comment: That is an important distinction. Personally, I try to avoid looping in my views in favour of display and editor templates - I find it makes things much cleaner. However, my models tend to be view-specific viewmodels, and not domain models as is probably the case here.

Comment: One thing you *could* do, is confine the display template to a particular controller view folder. Based on the way Razor templates are utilized, you can have `Views\Foo\DisplayTemplates` and `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates`. For any action on `FooController`, the display templates present in the `Foo` view folder will be utilized instead of those in `Shared`. This still assumes that all instances of `User` in these actions should be rendered the same way, but it's at least a little less global.